# List files and directories in linux

Tags: linux, ls

I am not very familiar with Linux. I have got root access of a server. When I run the command "ls" then it displays nothing. No error no information nothing. When I run "ls -l" it displays "total 0"

How do I list all files and directories?

Comment: This is a site for professional systems administrators. I'd hope that if you're administering Linux in a professional environment, you know how `ls` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `ls` lists the files and directories. If you have hidden files and folders, you can list them using:

```
$ ls -a
```

Adding the option `-l` gives a detailed list. You can see `man ls` for more options.

Comment: This actually did the trick. But strange thing is when I logged out of server and logged in again as root then this command didn't work. Then I tried "dir" and it worked which was previously not working. Weird!

Comment: Are you sure you are listing the contents of same folder after re-login? If so, check the system logs `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible that the directory you're in has been deleted from another shell/application/...

This would result in `ls -la` displaying `total 0`

Using `cd`, change again to the directory you want to list and retry.

Answer (score 0):

When you login as root, you are most likely in /root (root's home) which is often empty. Try "ls /" or "ls -lah /" to see the contents of the root of the filesystem tree.